# Update null to a value and insert to another table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem with php script. I have to insert values from one table to another. Both tables: observation and opinion has column name user_id. The issue is that in observation table some rows of user_id column are null, and in opinion table column user_id is set to not null. I want to insert all value from table observation to table opinion that actually have a value and if they not I want to change null to some value and then insert in opinion table.

This is my code which insert values, but the user_id value is setting to 99999 in every row:

```
$user = mysqli_query("SELECT user_id FROM observation;");

if ($user == NULL){
    $user = 99999;
}

$query = "INSERT INTO opinion(id, created_at, user_id, rating, updated_at, answer, description) 
    SELECT id, dateCreated, (". $user ."), grade, dateModerated, companyReply, note
    FROM observation
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id=observation.id, created_at=observation.dateCreated, user_id=". $user .", description=observation.note, rating=observation.grade, updated_at=observation.dateModerated, answer=observation.companyReply;";
mysqli_query($db, $query) or die('Error querying database.');
```

Comment: In `$user` isn't user_id but resource. Than you have there error in PHP, `mysqli_query` has 2 params.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to fetch the results of the query first:

```
$result = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT user_id FROM observation;");
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc();

if ($row['user_id'] == NULL){
    $user = 99999;
}else{
    $user = $row['user_id'];
}
```

Comment: should probably be $row['user_id']

Comment: Thanks. Wouldn't have noticed myself

Comment: Thank you it was the problem :)